# Looping through two models that contain lists and are connected Django

Tags: python, django

I'm a starter with Python/Django and I'm currently trying to make a basic app for making a collection log. First the user chooses a category and then inserts objects under that category.

I have two classes in models.py with the following code:

```
class object_category(models.Model):
"""This class contains the users different categories"""
CATEGORY_CHOICES = [
    ('category1', 'category1'),
    ('category2', 'category2'),
    ('category3', 'category3'),
]
"""Plural for multiple categories"""
class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'
    
"""Returns the above stated choices"""
category = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
def __str__(self):
    return self.category

class object_name(models.Model):
"""This class contains the object name that is housed within a certain category"""
"""Links the object to one of the chosen categories"""
category = models.ForeignKey(object_category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

# Placeholder for connection with a plant database API
object = models.CharField(max_length=50)

"""Return the object input from the user"""
def __str__(self):
    return self.object
```

and here is the views.py code:

```
def collection(request):
"""The page that opens the collection of objects"""
object_category = Object_category.objects.order_by('category')
object_name = Object_name.objects.order_by('object')

context = {
    'object_category': object_category,
    'object_name': object_name
}

return render(request, 'plntz_main/collection.html', context)
```

finnaly here is my html doc code:

```
{% for category in object_category %}
    {% for object in object_name %}
        <h3>{{ category }}</h3>
            <li>{{ object }}</li>
{% empty %}
    <li>No category has been added yet.</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This displays the category and the objects but they are not linked.

What I'm trying to display is:

- The categories the user selected
- Each object in that specific category

Can anyone explain how I alter the code do get this result ?

Sorry is this is a mess. I'm new and this is my first try on a project and my first question on stackoverflow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the documentation first and do some step by step basic tutorials, read docs here about filtering querysets [Django Querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/).

You can do something like this to achieve it

First, set related_name to your category foreign key

```
class object_name(models.Model):
"""This class contains the object name that is housed within a certain category"""
"""Links the object to one of the chosen categories"""
category = models.ForeignKey(object_category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='object_names')

# Placeholder for connection with a plant database API
object = models.CharField(max_length=50')

"""Return the object input from the user"""
def __str__(self):
    return self.object
```

Then in your views.py you just need to do

```
object_categories = Object_category.objects.all().order_by('category')

context = {
    'object_categories': object_categories,
}
```

and then I your template file do something like this:

```
    {% for category in object_categories %}
        <h3>{{ category }}</h3>
        {% for name in object_categories.object_names.all %}
                <li>{{ name.object }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% empty %}
        <li>No category has been added yet.</li>
    {% endfor %}
```

I did not test it, try yourself and see if it works :)

Comment: I'v tried the code out - i'v got the following result (I stopped hiding my category names because it was super confusing with the .objects):

Collection:
Houseplants
Outdoors
Succulents

So basically I get the Categories but not the names of the plants in the category. (I'v added some in the admin module).
Do I paste code again in a new post or what is the best way? @Baivaras

Comment: Sorry I did not really understand the issue you are having. If my above code works please mark it as the correct answer and open a new one for the new question. You can paste link here, I will help you out :) @de_l3ns

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply. Like you said I made a new question and put this one on resolved :). Here is the url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63676460/issue-with-using-query-in-django @baivaras