# Issue with using query in Django

Tags: python, django

So what I'm trying to get is the following.
User can choose 3 categories as seen in the code.

Inside those categories they can add any number of plants.
**In my view: collection I want the user to see the following:**

COLLECTION

Category_selected_by_user

- plant_1
- plant_2
- ....

Category_selected_by_user2

**What I get right now is:**

COLLECTION

Category_selected_by_user

Category_selected_by_user2

Category_selected_by_user3

so basically this is the code in models.py:

```py
class Plant_category(models.Model):
    """This class contains the users different categories"""
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = [
        ('Houseplant', 'Houseplant'),
        ('Succulents', 'Succulents'),
        ('Outdoor', 'Outdoor'),
    ]
    """Plural for multiple categories"""
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'
        
    """Returns the above stated choices"""
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class Plant_name(models.Model):
    """This class contains the plant name that is housed within a certain category"""
    """Links the plant to one of the chosen categories"""
    category = models.ForeignKey(Plant_category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='plant_names')
    
    # Placeholder for connection with a plant database API
    plant = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    """Return the plant input from the user"""
    def __str__(self):
        return self.plant
```

this is the code in views.py:

```py
def collection(request):
    """The page that opens the collection of plants"""
    plant_categories = Plant_category.objects.all().order_by('category')
    
    
    context = {
        'plant_categories': plant_categories,
    }
    
    return render(request, 'plntz_main/collection.html', context)
```

And this is the code in collection.html:

```html
<ul>
    {% for category in plant_categories %}
        <h3>{{ category }}</h3>
        {% for name in plant_categories.plant_names.all %}
            <li>{{ name.plant }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% empty %}
        <li>No category has been added yet.</li>        
    {% endfor %}

</ul>
```

There must be something wrong with the data pulled for the plants inside the category.
I can't seem to find what is causing this.

For example this is the admin data that has been added under Houseplant:

- houseplant_1
- houseplant_2

And this was added under Succulents:

- Cactus_1
- Cactus_2

Comment: Does the model `Plant_category` exist at all?

Comment: Yes it does, should I add it? @jonas

Comment: Yes, please... it is key

Comment: Yes, sorry! Done :) @Jonas

Comment: P.S. Triple quote strings are multiline.

Answer (score 0):

Imho this causes the problem: You don't refer to the object/queryset correctly, so no data is being rendered frontend wise.

Your context contains the object `plant_categories` which should be looped accordingly:

```
<ul>
{% for category in plant_categories %}
    <h3>{{ category }}</h3>

    # Refer to object within context
    {% for name in plant_categories %}

        <li>{{ name.plant }}</li> # Depending on what you would like to render you have to adapt here

    {% endfor %}
{% empty %}
    <li>No category has been added yet.</li>        
{% endfor %}
```

You can add a print statement to your view to check the queryset:

```
def collection(request):
"""The page that opens the collection of plants"""
plant_categories = Plant_category.objects.all().order_by('category')


context = {
    'plant_categories': plant_categories,
}

# Print for debugging
print(plant_categories)

return render(request, 'plntz_main/collection.html', context)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jonas . I tried editing the code accordingly and now I get the bulletin points but no actual data on the bullet point. So what I want to render with name.plant is the stored plant names in those specific categories. Sorry if this is really confusing, I'm very new to programming and I'm probably trying to go a little bit to fast here :)  - When I try to run that print function in my editor I get the following error:   File "views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .models import Plant_category, Plant_name
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: @de_l3ns your views.py file isn't able to import the required models from your models.py due to poor referencing. So in conclusion the view function isn't able to fetch any queryset since it doesn't have the model. Going further, no data can be rendered at the frontend since the context doesn't return any objects from your database. Make sure to fix those imports first of all :)

Comment: Ok @Jonas thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'm probably trying to run before I can walk but trial and error is the best learning tool I suppose! Cheers!

Comment: @de_l3ns good luck, feel free to ping me again. I'm around daily. Cheers

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I remembered you stating that I could ping you if I'd happen to need help again. Could you check out this django question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64090181/reverse-for-not-found-django - I made an EDIT to that post. Cheers. @Jonas