# Reverse for '' not found. - Django

Tags: python, django

I'm a beginner at Django/programming in general.
I have a problem with a redirecting url button on one of my HTML pages. Basically I have a collection page where one can add plants. Once a plant has been added, more details can be added to that plant. My CreateViews have been created, when I want to add the button to add details to an existing plant I get a reverse for not found error once I open the plant page.
The bold part in the html code is where I'm getting the error from.

models.py

```
class PlantDetail(models.Model):
    """This class contains various types of data of added plants"""
    """links the details to one plants"""
    from datetime import date
    plant = models.ForeignKey(Plant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_purchased = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    notes = models.TextField()
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        """Return the detail input from the user"""
        return self.notes
        
        
    def age(self):
        """Return the age of the plant in days"""
        age_days = datetime.date.today() - date_purchased
        return age_days.days

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail', args=[int(self.plant_id)])
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    # Landing page
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    
    # Collection page
    path('collection/', login_required(CollectionListView.as_view()), name='collection'),
    
    # Detail page for a plant
    path('collection/<int:plant_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),

    # New plant creation page
    path('collection/add/', login_required(PlantCreateView.as_view()), name='plant-create'),

    # Add details to an existing plant
    path('collection/<int:plant_id>/add_details/', login_required(PlantDetailCreateView.as_view()), name='plantdetail-create'),
```

views.py

```
class PlantDetailCreateView(CreateView):
    model = PlantDetail
    fields = ['date_purchased', 'notes']


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.plant_id = self.kwargs['plant_id']
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

details.html

```
    {% extends "plntz_main/base.html" %}
    
    {% block content %}
    <h1> {{ plant_detail.name }} </h1>
    <p><img src={{ plant_detail.image.url }}></p>
    <p> Nickname: {{ plant_detail.nickname}}
    <p> Category: {{ plant_detail.category }}
    {% for detail in plant_detail.plantdetail_set.all %}
        
        <p>Date purchased: {{ detail.date_purchased }} </p>
        <p>Notes: {{ detail.notes }}</p>
    
    {% endfor %}
<form>
    <button formaction="{% url 'plantdetail-create' request.plant.id %}">Add details</button>
</form>
    {% endblock content %}
```

EDIT: after typing error getting new error:
NoReverseMatch at /collection/1/
Reverse for 'plantdetail-create' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['collection/(?P<plant_id>[0-9]+)/add_details/$']

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple spelling error:

```
<button formaction="{% url 'plantdetail-create' request.plant.id %}">Add details</button>
```

Comment: oops I should have looked at formaction. Sorry

Comment: Hey @Biplove Lamichhane yes, true! That typo probably came from trying over and over. I get this error now: NoReverseMatch at /collection/1/
Reverse for 'plantdetail-create' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['collection/(?P<plant_id>[0-9]+)/add_details/$']

Comment: @Biplove Lamichhane I'm not sure, your comment seems to be cut off. Can you rephrase what you need me to update in my main question? I updated the typo comment right now :) cheers!

Comment: Please update ur question with what you have done in your system.

Comment: @jonas I remember you mentioning that I could ping you for django/python information. Would you mind taking a look as to what is giving me the error (see EDIT in main post) - cheers!

Comment: can u check what `request.plant.id` gives

Comment: Lol I banged my head for 30 mins looking for this. Spelling error as well